# call login page and register page in popup window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup, asp.net-ajax, loginview

i have to design an website use asp.net 
in this web site we have to use login and register
i use this code in master page

```
<asp:LoginView ID="Log_view" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate >
<span class="log_txt">Hi Guset! </span> &nbsp;
<a href="Register.aspx"  class="log_lnk"> Rigster</a>     &nbsp;                      
<a href="login.aspx" class="log_lnk">Login</a>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
<asp:LoginName ID="Log_name" runat="server" CssClass="log_txt" FormatString="Hi, {0}!"/>
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server"  LogoutText="Logout" CssClass="log_lnk" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" LogoutAction="Redirect" OnLoggingOut="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut" />        </LoggedInTemplate>  
</asp:LoginView>
```

and its work without any problem, but the login page and register page will display normal, i want to display in popup window.

in other page i use this script to call page in popup window use AjaxControlToolkit and its work fine

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<span>
<a href="#" id="Rig_log" runat="server" > Rigister | Login </a>
</span>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Rig_log" CancelControlID="btn_close" BackgroundCssClass="popup_Background">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<cc1:DragPanelExtender ID="Image1_DragPanelExtender" runat="server" 
Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Panl1" DragHandleID="Panl1">
</cc1:DragPanelExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">
<div id="popup_header"> <span>Register | Login </span><a href="#" ID="btn_close" runat="server" > X </a></div>
<div id="popup_content"> <iframe id="irm1" src="Register_login.aspx" runat="server"></iframe></div>
</asp:Panel>
```

my issue is , how i can call login page and register page in popup, i try but it's not working

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hanashi,

You can try out java script below like this.

window.open(your page name);

Dinesh Nagrale